# Making a deck of cards in Python

Tags: python, beginner, playing-cards

I want to have a deck of cards that looks like this:

['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6'...]

For that I wrote the following code:

```
    import itertools
    kind = 'HCDS'
    value = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
    temp = list(itertools.product(kind,value))

    deck = []
    for i in range(0, len(temp)): 
        (a,b) = temp[i]
        deck.append(a+b)
    print(deck)
```

I was wondering if it could be done easier without the use of this temp variable or the for loop.

Comment: One (off-topic) suggestion - just to ease parsing and keystrokes - use "T" for 10...  (eg. '9', 'T', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ])

Comment: Since this is code review: the proper way to do this would be to have a list of (immutable) objects with `suit` and `value` properties..

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft you may want to add that as an answer, so it's not lost in the comments for the next person who sees this question. I had the same thought when I was initially looking at this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could just use `str.join` in a list comprehension and create `deck` directly:

```
import itertools 
kind = 'HCDS' 
value = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
deck = ["".join(card) for card in itertools.product(kind,value)]
```

Note that a regular French card set starts at `2`, there is no `1`.

Answer (score 10):

You can unpack the tuple directly in the list comprehension and use `+` to join the cards.

```
In [12]: kind = 'HCDS'
In [13]: value = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']
In [14]: deck = [k + v for k, v in itertools.product(kind, value)]
In [15]: deck[:4], deck[-4:]
Out[15]: (['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4'], ['SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'SA'])
```

Also, instead of using `itertools.product`, you could use a double-for-loop list comprehension:

```
In [16]: deck = [k + v for k in kind for v in value]
In [17]: deck[:4], deck[-4:]
Out[17]: (['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4'], ['SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'SA'])
```

Not that it matters much in this example, but for just joining two strings, `+` is quite a bit faster than `join`, and the double-for-loop also seems to be a bit faster then `itertools.product`:

```
In [21]: %timeit ["".join(card) for card in itertools.product(kind,value)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.4 us per loop
In [22]: %timeit [k + v for k, v in itertools.product(kind, value)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.1 us per loop
In [23]: %timeit [k + v for k in kind for v in value]
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.5 us per loop
```